# How to redraw chart : d3.js chaining function and crossfilter filtering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, method-chaining, brush

#### Edit : JSBin dont work go to [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjphhusx/3/) to see my code

I'm training my self with `d3` and `crossfilter` and i face some difficulties.
I'm trying to make a chaining function to create bar chart. *The idea is to not write all the code again and again for each bar chart i want to create.*
I was inspired by the example [Fast Multidimensional Filtering for Coordinated Views](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) which is what i wanted to do (you can find code [Here](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/gh-pages/index.html)).

But I want to bring some personal touches in my generic barChart function.
I decided to do it with chaining function like in the example.
I understood how to create as many graphics as you wish, but i dont understand, *(when brushes event appears)*, how to redraw all the bar depending on the filter.

If i wanted to do it outside a function i would define again the all the properties like x, y, axis etc. depending on the new data which is the filtered data like this:

```
var updateRange = function(filt){
    data = dimension.filter(filt) //assuming dimension is a crossfilter dimension
    // Scale the range of the data again 
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.key; })+1]);

// Select the section we want to apply our changes to

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
//Update all rects

chart.selectAll("rect.hidden")
   .data(data)
   .transition()
   .delay(function(d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
   .duration(500)
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y2(d.value);
   })
   .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y2(d.value);
});
```

I made a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wotunuv/2/edit?js,output) to discuss on how we can make the chart updated.
And this is the `brush` functions i use.

```
brush.on("brushstart", function() {
  var div = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
  div.select(".title a").style("display", null);
});

brush.on("brush", function() {
  var g = d3.select(this.parentNode),
    extent = brush.extent();
  if (round) g.select(".brush")
    .call(brush.extent(extent = extent.map(round)))
    .selectAll(".resize")
    .style("display", null);
  g.select("#clip-" + id + " rect")
    .attr("x", x(extent[0]))
    .attr("width", x(extent[1]) - x(extent[0]));
  dimension.filter(extent);
});

brush.on("brushend", function() {
  if (brush.empty()) {
    var div = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
    div.select(".title a").style("display", "none");
    div.select("#clip-" + id + " rect").attr("x", null).attr("width", width);
    dimension.filterAll();
  }
)};
```

waiting for your comments,
Chris.

#### Edit : some clarification

To be clearer, when i render the chart and use the brush the data are correctly filtered. *(if i put some console.log i see the data filtered depending on the brush)*
But the chart are not updated depending on the brush. I know the issue come from th way i used the brush event (`brush.on(`).
I think i need to call the render function in some way but dont know how to do it with chaining function to be applied to all the charts.

#### Edit : Chart updated with external brush

The chart are now successfully updated when the brush is set externally (*by clicking on the link*).
Just adding this lines

```
if (brushDirty) {
  brushDirty = false;
  g.selectAll(".brush").call(brush);
  div.select(".title a").style("display", brush.empty() ? "none" : null);
  if (brush.empty()) {
    g.selectAll("#clip-" + id + " rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", width);
  } else {
    var extent = brush.extent();
    g.selectAll("#clip-" + id + " rect")
        .attr("x", x(extent[0]))
        .attr("width", x(extent[1]) - x(extent[0]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to update charts you can remove it and then redraw with new filters.
Something like this :

```
 d3.selectAll(".chart").selectAll("svg").remove();
```

Or

```
 $('#chart'+chart_id+' svg').remove();
```

and then redraw it by calling again your drawing function with updated data.

Hope this will help you. Sorry If I misunderstood you. I need to train my english =P

**EDIT :**

I found these examples without remove. It might help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/sx9myywh/

https://bl.ocks.org/RandomEtc/cff3610e7dd47bef2d01

Comment: Not you understand me ! (i dont think my english is good...).
I think the solution you proposed will work but i dont know if it's optimal to delete all the graphics and redraw all of them.

Comment: If you find an other solution, please share it. In my own project I use this above method (that works well) but I would be interested to find an other/(better?) way to do this.

Comment: I will. Thank you for taking the time to reply

Comment: My bad. On this example data isn't recalculated it's just a zoom on axis.

Comment: Yes. In my example i use `crossfilter` to filter variable depending on brush. I know that dc.js to that well, but i need for my project to do it only from d3.js and crossfilter.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore what you want to do but I found this, it's not unlike your example : http://jsfiddle.net/jth32/22/

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want as result. But this example use the library `dc.js`, and i cant use it for my project. As you can see in the example you link, they used chaining function to generate chart (like the `barChart` function i created). But i dont understand how to refresh graph created like this depending on brush. (i know how to do it when i create graphs one by one outside a chaining function)

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was. And i feel stupid.

The `brush.on`event was placed incide the function which generate the chart and have to be outside.

```
function my(div){

}
brush.on(...
```

I have updated the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjphhusx/5/) with the correct answer.
I will create a github repository it will be cleaner.